# Workaround for missing EnumBuilder in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, enums, cil

I'm trying to convert a project from .NET Framework to .NET Core, but I've run into the problem that `System.Reflection.Emit.EnumBuilder.CreateType` is not implemented in .NET Core.  How can I dynamically implement an Enum in .NET Core?  Is there some magic CIL that will do this or some way to emulate an Enum?

Answer (score 2):

It took a few hours to reverse-engineer this, but here it is:

```
    class EnumTypeBuilder
    {
        private TypeBuilder _enumTypeBuilder;

        public EnumTypeBuilder(ModuleBuilder builder, string name, TypeAttributes attributes, Type underlyingType)
        {
            _enumTypeBuilder = builder.DefineType(name, attributes | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Sealed, typeof(System.Enum), PackingSize.Unspecified, TypeBuilder.UnspecifiedTypeSize);
            FieldBuilder valueFieldBuilder = _enumTypeBuilder.DefineField("value__", underlyingType, FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.SpecialName | FieldAttributes.RTSpecialName);
        }

        public void DefineLiteral(string name, object value)
        {
            FieldBuilder enumerationFieldBuilder = _enumTypeBuilder.DefineField(name, _enumTypeBuilder, FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Literal);
            enumerationFieldBuilder.SetConstant(value);
        }

        public Type CreateType()
        {
            return _enumTypeBuilder.CreateType();
        }
    }
```

This appears to generate types that behave exactly like an Enum in every way I can find.  Note that the type passed into DefineLiteral must match the underlying type passed into the constructor.

Comment: That is really close to the reference implementation in .net Framework, good job. You could return the `FieldBuilder` from the `DefineLiteral` call like the 'original': https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/enumbuilder.cs,09a6dfd8f8f26ac9

Comment: such a good effort! thanks a lot